# the backgroung image not showing up in browser

Tags: html, css

I have used background-image its being detected in the chrome but not getting displayed in the browser.can anyone help
thanks in advance.

css

```
.home-inner
{
    background-image: url(../images/Slider/Slider.jpg);
}
```

html

Comment: Check your image url. You can cross check by looking in the Network tab if that image is being fetched properly..

Comment: If you are not viewing your image in the object inspector of your browser, then the problem is in the url.

Comment: Try checking if the image-url is right in the Browser's Developer Tools. Else you can try putting the same link for an <img /> and check it too

Comment: kindly, tell your project's structure

Comment: We don't really have enough information here to be able to help. The most likely problem is with the path, as has already been suggested, however we can't offer much more help without having more information. If it is a path problem, we are unable to help without more information about your site structure. If it is not a path problem, please take a look at how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: the image displayed using img tag cannot make them fill the screen

Comment: project structure

index.html
Assets 
|css->style.css
|images->slider->slider.jpg
|js->loader.js

Answer (score 0):

```css
.home-inner{ 
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
  background-image: url("http://coursehd.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/5-tips-market-yourself-elearning-professional.jpg"); }
```

```html
<div class="landing"> <div class="home-wrap"> <div class="home-inner"> </div> </div> </div>
```

Comment: give more details.

Comment: i have given the path above the project structure and the code is uploaded need the full code of the project?

Comment: no, just .home-inner section html and css code is require.

Comment: <div class="landing">
    <div class="home-wrap">
      <div class="home-inner">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

css
.home-inner{
    background-image: url("/Assets/images/Slider/Slider.jpg");
}

Comment: i edited code and it works. maybe you have 2 mistake: 1- home-wrap has no width and height or 2- your url path or image name in not correct

Answer (score -1):

Give image path should be inside sinle / double quotation. And also check the directory path.

```
background-image: url("../images/Slider/Slider.jpg");
```

Comment: have tried the quotes also, the directory path is also correct but the image not showing up.

Comment: FYI Using quotes might be good practice, but isn't necessary.